What exactly lea call does with SI register and a variable in data segment?
The problem is checking whether a substring exists in a string input by user. As I understand, in main proc, the program calls lea si, inputstring which means SI points the inputstring in data segement (which means SI holds the memory address of inputstring). However, in subroutine findstringktmt, we move that value of SI to CX, which implies to me that CX now actually stores the number of characters in the inputstring. So what's exactly going in this code?
.model small

.data
    inputstring db 100 dup('?')
    findstring  db 'ktmt'
    result      db 0
    crlf        db 13, 10, '$'      ;carriage return and line feed

.code  

;subfunction to get character
getchar:
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    ret
    
;subfunction to read string from screen
getstring:
    call getchar
    inc si
    mov [inputstring + si], al
    cmp al, '#'
    jne getstring
    ret

;subfunction to check if 'ktmt' exist in the input string
findstringktmt: 
    mov cx, si
    lea si, inputstring + 1
    lea di, findstring
    mov bh, 0
    
    find:
        mov al, [si]
        mov bl, [di]
        cmp bl, al
        je  if_equal
        lea di, findstring - 1
        mov bh, -1
        if_equal:
            inc di
            inc bh
            cmp bh, 4
            je  found
        inc si
        loop find
    
    ret
    found:
        mov [result], 1
    ret
    
;print result to the screen
printresult:
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, crlf
    int 21h
    mov dl, [result]
    add dx, 48
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    ret
    
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    lea si, inputstring
    call getstring
    call findstringktmt
    call printresult
    int 20h
main endp
end main


I am confused by my textbook, it says SI holds the the actual address of inputstring. However it may seems like SI has the offset address, which also equals to the characters read

After calling getstring, si holds the address of the terminating character, the # that getstring explicitly is looking for. In findstringktmt that value (address) is copied into cx, and then si is changed to point to the second character (?) of findstring. In no case does si nor cx hold the number of characters typed . It may happen that these variables are conveniently stored at the bottom of the address space in play here, in which it would contain the number of characters, but this should not be relied upon.

Yes, that is broken code. The lea si, inputstring takes the address but then it is used as an index in mov [inputstring + si], al. si should just be initialized to zero. It is also confusing that getstring starts writing at the second byte, which is why lea si, inputstring + 1 is used in findstringktmt.
